# Change value inside a dictionary with function

Tags: python

I want to change the value of x to 10 by using the table as an argument but it doesn't change value. I also don't want to modify arguments hence copy(). What do I need to do?

```
def change_x(table):
    new_table = table.copy()
    new_table['x'] = 10

def main():
    table = {
        'x': 8,
        'y': 10
    }
    print(table) # prints 8
    change_x(table) # change value of x to 10
    print(table) # prints 8, wanted 10
```

Comment: Your two requirements contradict with each other. You said you don't want to modify the argument(which is a dictionary) hence you copied, then you say I want to change `x` to 10. If you don't `.copy()` everything is ok. Otherwise you can return the *new* dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`.copy()` is a reference to the location where the value is stored and hence it does not change the value. You have to either get rid of the `.copy()` to change the value or you can return the new dictionary from the `change_x` function.

```
def change_x(table):
    table['x'] = 10

def main():
    table = {
        'x': 8,
        'y': 10
    }
    print(table) # prints 8
    change_x(table) # change value of x to 10
    print(table) # prints 10, wanted 10
```

**OR**

```
def change_x_1(table):
        table['x'] = 10
        return table

def main():
        table = {
            'x': 8,
            'y': 10
        }

print(table) # prints 8
print( change_x_1(table) ) # change value of x to 10 and it returns 10, wanted 10
```

Comment: Isn't `table["x"] = 10` enough?

Comment: @S.B My bad, yes its more than enough :) Thanks